# Using BLAS or LAPACK with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, lapack, blas, complex-numbers

I'm looking for a good guide on how to incorporate BLAS or LAPACK functions into my Objective C Program developed through Xcode.  The only sources I can find online of programs in BLAS/LAPACK are written in Fortran - this is confusing.  How does one make use of BLAS/LAPACK and still code in Objective C? Are there any online examples/guides? I want to be able to perform matrix operations where elements of the matrix have complex values.

Cheers,

Shaddy

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683080/performing-matrix-operations-with-complex-numbers-in-c/7683366#7683366

Comment: I know that GNU scientific library (in C++) has interfaces to LAPACK and BLAS. Try looking at their code. I dont know much about objective C but that might be a start.

Comment: CBLAS is part of the Accelerate framework that ships on every Mac and iOS device.

Answer (score 6):

the headers for the C interfaces are `cblas.h` and `clapack.h`. they are part of the vecLib framework, which is part of the Accelerate framework.